# Docked text view - doing it properly

Tags: ios, chat, messaging, inputaccessoryview

I want to achieve the same user experience as many messaging apps - that is where Text View is visible at the bottom of the screen, and when tapped it goes up with the keyboard. It can be done multiple ways - i.g. moving the text view up based on the keyboard notification. But AFAIR the best way to do it is overriding the `inputAccessoryView` of `UIViewController`. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        get {
            return self.textFieldContainer
        }
    }

}
```

It works. However when I embed it in navigation controller some view artifacts/glitches are present. Please check the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sx2yg5pFOZo

Any feedback much appreciated.

Additional question: how can I notify the view controller that inputAccessoryView changed? So i.g. I can display and hide the text view whenever I want?

Please note: I've tried Slack Text View Controller. They must be using some UI hacks, as I see some glowing effect on the input view during pushing in navigation controller.

Kind regards
Chris